# What is going on with Args..., Args&..., Args&&

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have this code.  To get it to work I had to use Args&&... instead of Args... or Args&... I notice the args convert from & to const& or && to &.  What exactly is going on with Args... Args&... and Args&&... !?

**When the signature was Args..**

```
template<class V, class F, class... Args> void
Parse(int n, V& v, const F& f, Args... args)
```

Parse(20150201, y,4, m,2, d, 2) would only populate y=2015.

While debugging the first recursion of the function, I saw this:

```
f      4 const int&
v      0 int&
args_0 2 int
args_1 0 int         <-- needs to be int&
args_2 2 int
args_3 0 int         <-- needs to be int&
```

The second iteration looked like this:

```
f      4 const int&
v      0 int&        <-- this refs the int on the first level, not m
args_0 2 int          
args_1 0 int         <-- needs to be int&
```

The third iteration looked like this:

```
f      4 const int&
v      0 int&        <-- this refs the int on the 2nd level, not d
```

So it doesn't work.

**When the signature was Args&...:**

```
template<class V, class F, class... Args> void
Parse(int n, V& v, const F& f, Args&... args)
```

Parse(20150201, y,4, m,2, d, 2) produced this compiler error.

```
Variadac.cpp(360): error C2664: 'void Parse<int,int,int,int,int,int>(int,V &,const F &,int &,int &,int &,int&)' : cannot convert argument 5 from 'int' to 'int &' with [V=int,F=int]
```

I take it '2' can not be int&.

**When the signature was Args&&...:**

```
template<class V, class F, class... Args> void
Parse(int n, V& v, const F& f, Args&&... args)
```

Parse(20150201, y,4, m,2, d, 2) would populate y=2015, m=2, d=1 which is correct.

While debugging the first recursion of the function, I saw this:

```
f      4 const int&
v      0 int&
args_0 2 int&
args_1 0 int&&
args_2 2 int&
args_3 0 int&&
```

The second iteration looked like this:

```
f      4 const int&
v      0 int&        <-- hey! this was int &&
args_0 2 int&          
args_1 0 int&        <-- hey! this was int &&
```

The 3rd iteration looked like this:

```
f      4 const int&
v      0 int&
```

int&& is being used with some arguments and int& with others.

Here is the code.  It is trying to be a universal parser of different snippets of digits from an integral number.

```
int Pow(const int n) {
    switch (n) {
    case 1: return 10;
    case 2: return 100;
    case 3: return 1000;
    case 4: return 10000;
    case 5: return 100000;
    case 6: return 1000000;
    case 7: return 10000000;
    case 8: return 100000000;
    case 9: return 1000000000;
    }
}

template<class V, class F, class... Args> int
Pow(V& v, const F& f, Args... args) {
    return Pow(f) * Pow(args...);
}
template<class V, class F> int
Pow(V& v, const F& f) {
    return Pow(f);
}

// Parse(1234, a, 2, b, 2)
template<class V, class F, class... Args> void
Parse(int n, V& v, const F& f, Args&&... args) {
    const int p = Pow(args...);
    v = n / p;
    Parse(n % p, args...);
}
// Parse(100, n, 3)
template<class V, class F> INL void
Parse(int n, V& v, const F& f) {
    v = n;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int y, m, d;
    Parse(20150210+argc, y, 4, m, 2, d, 2);
    return y + m + d;
}
```

I am happy with this code since it seems to unravel the loop and produce loop free assembly.  I don't know if this is good assembly and I haven't profiled different ways of pulling the digits off (right now I use n%p which has profiled better than n - v*p in other areas).  On the surface it looks like all the divides and modulus are compile time deduced.

```
    Parse(20150210+argc, y, 4, m, 2, d, 2);
000000013F9C3274  imul        esi  
000000013F9C3276  mov         edi,edx  
000000013F9C3278  sar         edi,0Ch  
000000013F9C327B  mov         eax,edi  
000000013F9C327D  shr         eax,1Fh  
000000013F9C3280  add         edi,eax  
000000013F9C3282  imul        eax,edi,2710h  
000000013F9C3288  sub         esi,eax  
000000013F9C328A  mov         eax,51EB851Fh  
000000013F9C328F  imul        esi  
000000013F9C3291  mov         ebx,edx  
000000013F9C3293  sar         ebx,5  
000000013F9C3296  mov         eax,ebx  
000000013F9C3298  shr         eax,1Fh  
000000013F9C329B  add         ebx,eax  
000000013F9C329D  imul        eax,ebx,64h  
000000013F9C32A0  sub         esi,eax
```

Comment: reference-collapsing rule: `& &` / `&& &` / `& &&` => `&`, `&& &&` => `&&`. See perfect forwarding and forwarding-reference.

Comment: Why does it make int&, int&&, int&, int&& instead of int&&, int&&, int&&, int&& ?

Comment: Ok, the comma was hard to see.   & & / && & / & && => &   AND    && && => &&

Comment: so the rvalues come in with type T or T&& AND the lvalues come in with type T&.   T&& or T&& && => T&& AND T& && => T&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deducing a template argument `T` with an argument of the form `T&&` the type `T` will retain whether it is an lvalue or an rvalue as well as the cv-qualifiers for lvalues. That is if you pass an object of type `X` to a function declared as

```
template <typename T> void f(T&& t);
```

you'll get the following types:

- `f(X())` => `T == X`
- `X x; f(x)` => `T == X&`
- `X const& xc; f(x)` => `T == X const&`

Whether the arguments are deduced individually or via variadic arguments doesn't make any difference. Within `f()` the argument `t` is always an lvalue as it has a name. Thus, calling a function from `f()` with the argument will not consider the argument to be an rvalue. If you want to forward the argument and retain its properties as in the original call, you'll need to use `std::forward()`:

```
g(std::forward<T>(t));
```

The call to `std:: forward()` will simply cause the argument to appear of the the same kind as the argument to the original template.

Comment: *"as well as the cv-qualifiers for lvalues"* and rvalues? Only prvalues of non-class, non-array type lose their cv-qualification.

Comment: T == X  ==> X&& t;  T == X&  ==> X& && ==> X?

Comment: Parse(20150201, y, 4, m, 2, d, 2).  y becomes int&, 4 becomes int&&.  To retain whether lvalue or rvalue it must be & or && - it cant be & or nothing?

Comment: Is it safe to say that when i use args... the compiler is wrapping each individual arg in std::forward? Like this: std::forward<Arg_0>(arg_0).

Comment: 1. The types for `T` are deduced as state and get the `&&` applied. If a `&&` is applied to a reference type it is collapes, i.e. `X& &&` is equivalent to `X&`. 2. Yes, there is no way to deduce lvalueness/rvaluenss than using something which ends up passing a reference. 3. No. With in the function all arguments are considered lvalues (they have a name). If you want forward lvaluness/rvalueness you'll need to use `std::forward<Args>(args)...` explicitly.